# Image delete produces error: "Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: The operation 'deleteObject' cannot be performed on a root reference"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to to delete a document in firebase storage and firestore but i'm getting an error. I'm using react.

```
const onDelete = (e) => {
    const { url } = e.target;
    console.log("Url", url);
    const deleteRef = ref(storage, url);

    deleteObject(deleteRef)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Item was deleted from Firebase Storage", deleteRef);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
        toast.error(error.message);
      });

    const imageDelete = db.collection("images").where("imageURL", "==", url);
    imageDelete.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        doc.ref.delete();
      });
      console.log("Image should have been deleted from Firestore");
    });
  };
```

The error that i get is:

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: The operation 'deleteObject' cannot be performed on a root reference, create a non-root reference using child, such as .child('file.png'). (storage/invalid-root-operation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, you're trying to delete the root of a Storage bucket - which isn't possible.

From looking at your code that build the reference, it seems that `url` is empty, so you'll want to check the output you get from:

```
console.log("Url", url);
```

Comment: Thanks, it was empty indeed. My attempts to delete the data in Firestore are fruitless. My code for deleting is above. I know the DB reference was incorrect but even after fixing it, i'm still getting a ```n.indexOf is not a function```. Apparently its an "over-asked" question but the answers on this platform seem outdated.

Comment: Good to hear my guess was correct.  --- That "n.indexOf is not a function" sounds like a new problem. I'm pretty sure we had the same error message before, so check if you can find a solution by [searching for that message](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+Firebase+n.indexOf+is+not+a+function). If that doesn't solve it, I recommend posting an new question with its own minimal repro.